# how to do the collapsible header in collection view supplementary header view when scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing a collapsible header but the header is in a collectionview supplementary header view. How to do the collapsible header and set a specific size when scrolling?

Can you give me any example? or links that could help my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to see how.

https://medium.com/@mail2ashislaha/stretchy-header-animation-using-collection-view-custom-layout-f2ce466ec710

You should learn about [contentOffset] of [collectionView] before starting.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this is to have your collapsable header be a separate view that you manage alongside your collectionView using contentOffset/contentInset. This header would be at the same level as the collectionView in the view hierarchy.

As you scroll, you can either shrink or expand the header while defining some min-height and max-height values for it. These values will come in handy when managing the collectionView.

If you want to get even fancier, you can have animations in the header that trigger at certain contentOffset points.